# Localization vs. submitting app several times

Tags: ios, iphone

I am planning on first launching my app in a non-english-speaking country. After the launch, I plan on localizing the app (not only translate it but change content too) and launch it in an english-speaking country under the same name.

How should I go about this, i.e., will Apple let me launch the app in one country first, and then 1 month later under the same name in a different country? So, can I submit the same app twice (same name but slightly different content and different language)?

I know apps can be localized, but to my knowledge this only refers to strings/calendars and so on, not actual content.

Please let me know if any of you have experience with this!

All the best

Answer (score 0):

You can change the content (strings, user interfaces) based on the different locales, since you can always check to see what locale the user is in and react to that. Although, if you're going to have separate functionality for different applications, you may want to use two different applications. It depends on your use case.

For localization guides and information , I recommend 
https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/ and
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios